# What is the image of the function $f: (0, \infty) \rightarrow R, f(x) = \frac{4x}{x+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I attempted to solve this question using a method learned from a previous answer on here. I was just looking for a bit more guidance.
This is what I have for this problem:

> $y=\frac{4x}{x+1}\\
> y(x+1) =4x \\
> yx + y = 4x \\
> y = 4x-yx \\
> y= x(4-y) \\
> \frac{y}{4-y}=x \\
> \frac{y}{4-y} > 0  \\
> 0 < y < 4  $

Is this the correct approach? Also, it says to prove my answer. Would this just be doing the same steps in reverse?
Thanks,

EDIT: It came to my attention that proving it might just be plugging in the values and showing that they satisfy the original domain + target space. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac {4x}{x+1}=\dfrac{4x+4-4}{x+1}=4-\dfrac {4}{x+1}$

When $x$ tends to $0$ then $4-\dfrac {4}{x+1}$ tends to $0$. When $x$ tends to $+\infty$ then $4-\dfrac {4}{x+1}$ tends to $4$.

So, because your function is continuous your image is $(0,4)$.

Alternative approach:

$\dfrac {y}{4-y} >0$

This is possible if and only if $y>0$ and $4-y>0$ or if $y<0$ and $4-y<0$. See what case out of these two cases is possible.

Comment: And I can prove it by just subbing it back in and verifying that it passes the conditions?

Comment: like that? I'm not exactly sure where I went wrong. Which steps were correct?

Comment: Ah.. I see. I only used one of the two cases without taking into account the other one. So if I illustrate both cases and find the correct one, my solution is acceptable?

Comment: @CraigD Of course, when you discard impossible case you are left with only one case which tells you what is the image. But there is still much that you have to learn.

Comment: Hopefully I will understand the rest from lectures. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{4x}{x+1}
=\frac{4x+4-4}{x+1}
=\frac{4(x+1)-4}{x+1}
=4-\frac{4}{x+1}
$

Now, the ranges.

$\begin{array}\\
x+1: 
&(0, \infty)\to (1, \infty)\\
\frac1{x}:
&(1, \infty) \to (0, 1)\\
4x:
&(0, 1)\to (0, 4)\\
4-x:
&(0, 4) \to 0, 4)\\
\end{array}
$
So the range is
$(0, 4)$.